# List of files (including hidden) in a folder and all subfolders

Tags: command-prompt

I have used a linux command to create a csv list of all files (both hidden and not) off my hard drive.

A picture of the result is added from using the command:

```
find /media/disk1 -type f -print0 | xargs -0 stat -c '"%n",%s,%y' >disk1.csv
```

[image]

In Windows, When I have run `dir /a /s > filelist.csv`, the result comes up like a tree format with each file list under its directory

[image]

What command can I use to print just a list of each file's pathname, size, and last modification date, without their directory heading? I'm essentially wanting the same format output as the Linux csv, but in Windows.

Thanks

Comment: Possibly try asking over at [unix stack exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com)

Comment: But it's a windows question?

Comment: `>disk1.csv (for /F "delims=" %G in ('dir /S /B /A J:\') do @echo "%~fG",%~zG,%~tG)`. Related: [How to format dir command in cmd for XP and Win 2000](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30778699/3439404).